# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

my .htaccess rule look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^main index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tags tags.php [L]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]*)/page([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&timesort=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&timesort=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

i get 500 internal error each time i visit these page. only page work is index.php

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules with end anchors:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^main/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/?$ tags.php [L]

RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]+)/?$ audios.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]+)/page([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&timesort=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page([^/]*)$ audios.php?type=$1&timesort=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: after added the Options -MultiViews and ending anchors now it become 404

Comment: update: if visit the page: http://www.domain.com/login/ (with ending anchors) =  it works but http://www.domain.com/login become 404

Comment: @David - those are identical... Which one works, and which one throws a 404?

Comment: @MikeRockett when visiting the login page with ending anchor it works, but without ending anchor it become 404

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteRule ^login/ login.php [L]` when I suggested `RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]` (I made trailing `/` optional)

Comment: ok sorry my mistake. now the login works.. but not for audios

Comment: audio i use the exact you suggest too:
RewriteRule ^audios/([^/]+)/?$ audios.php?type=$1 [L,QSA] it does not work.. 500 internal error

Comment: btw you still have bad `RewriteRule ^audios audios.php [L]` rule. That should be: `RewriteRule ^audios/?$ audios.php [L]` (note addition of `/?$` in all rules like that)

Comment: last comment fixed that.. i did not notice there is another bad rule below it.. thank you very much.. i spend 2-3 hours google around, you saved my day.